# svg pie chart animation looks clumsy on firefox

Tags: css, firefox, svg

Please help me with this PIE chart animation. The animation works perfectly on chrome but on firefox it just shows something else (kind of weird). Please check the below screenshot:

[image]

[Here is the fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pie-chart-animation-b4a3q7?file=index.html)

The issues I have seen on firefox are:

- Showing outline when the animation is in progress
- pie lines are not perfectly straight

Comment: Which version of Firefox do you have? I see this with the outlines, but the lines are straight.

Comment: 65.02 version.. updating now

Comment: bumped to 66 version, still the same issue

Comment: Best if you draw the pie segments using elliptical arcs rather than abusing stroke-dasharray.

Comment: As Robert said. Using `stroke-width` as a way to fake fill a circle is not reliable. Choose a method that draws proper circular segments instead.

Comment: @RobertLongson and Paul LeBeau, Thanks, I am trying the same but it is getting hard for me to plot the coordinates as per the varying percentages for each pie chart.  Any easy formula to plot this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using firefox version 75.0 and it seems solved with an update to firefox.

Comment: except you can't use 'calc' in stroke-dasharray with firefox yet.

Comment: I believe Chrome will be removing their invalid implementation of calc in this regard.